# trying to join 4 tables with mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to join 4 tables but having issues. my code is listed below.

The error I recieve is

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON advancedcatalog_font_type.id = advancedcatalog_dimensions.font_type_id) LEFT ' at line 6
```

### advancedcatalog_dimensions

```
id         |letter_id    |    font_type_id     |  font_size_id  |   dimensions   |   LED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1        |             |                     |                |                |
  2        |             |                     |                |                |
  3        |             |                     |                |                |
  4        |             |                     |                |                |
```

### advancedcatalog_font_size

```
id         |font_size    |   
--------------------------
  1        |             |   
  2        |             | 
  3        |             |   
  4        |             |
```

### advancedcatalog_font_type

```
id         |font_name    |    
--------------------------
  1        |             | 
  2        |             |   
  3        |             |   
  4        |             |
```

### advancedcatalog_letter

```
id         |casing       |    letter           |  
------------------------------------------------
  1        |             |                     |  
  2        |             |                     |
  3        |             |                     |     
  4        |             |                     |
```

Query that works:

```
   SELECT advancedcatalog_letter.letter, 
          advancedcatalog_dimensions.dimensions, 
          advancedcatalog_font_type.font_name       
     FROM (advancedcatalog_dimensions
LEFT JOIN advancedcatalog_letter ON advancedcatalog_dimensions.letter_id = advancedcatalog_letter.id) 
LEFT JOIN advancedcatalog_font_type ON advancedcatalog_font_type.id = advancedcatalog_dimensions.font_type_id
    LIMIT 0 , 400
```

Query that does ***NOT*** work:

```
   SELECT advancedcatalog_letter.letter, 
          advancedcatalog_dimensions.dimensions, 
          advancedcatalog_font_type.font_name       
     FROM (advancedcatalog_dimensions
LEFT JOIN advancedcatalog_letter ON advancedcatalog_dimensions.letter_id = advancedcatalog_letter.id) 
LEFT JOIN (advancedcatalog_font_type ON advancedcatalog_font_type.id = advancedcatalog_dimensions.font_type_id)
LEFT JOIN advancedcatalog_font_size ON advancedcatalog_font_size.id = advancedcatalog_dimensions.font_size_id
```

Comment: It might make your life easier to alias the table names in your queries--`advancedcatalog_letter` can be abbreviated `l` without confusion, `advancatedcatalog_font_type` => `ft`, etc.

Comment: Quoting the error would help too--"having issues" ranges from syntax errors to not correct data.  Also, the brackets aren't necessary in the JOIN criteria for either examples.  They'd go around the join criteria specifically (the stuff after the "ON"), not encapsulate table name declarations...

Comment: You are right. My fault. I listed the error above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`advancedcatalog_dimensions.font_size_id` does not exist and you are referencing it in your second query.

Comment: my apologize. that was a error on my part. font_size_id does exist in the table

Comment: It's probably your bracketing then - remove all brackets.

Comment: You are right. Thanks alot. I was falling a tutorial that used the parenthesis so I figure that is how it was done. But I wonder why it works with 2 left joins but not we 3.